# How to resolve the following error Product() in Product cannot be applied?

Tags: java, android

[image]

Here i have declared the product class variables and assigned it.

product.java

```
public class Product {
    String[] name= new String[100];
    int price;
    int image;
    boolean box;


    Product(String[] _describe, int _price, int _image, boolean _box) {
        name = _describe;
        price = _price;
        image = _image;
        box = _box;
    }
}
```

This is my product class. What should i change in the above coding??
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 String[] data =new String[] {"no:1","no:2","no:3","no:4","no:5","no:6"};
    String[] columnTags = new String[] {"ProcessName", "IpItem", "IpColor", "OpItem","OpColor", "PlanQty", "DcQty", "RecQty", "RtQty"};
    ArrayList products = new ArrayList();
    ListAdapter1 boxAdapter;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fillData();
    boxAdapter = new ListAdapter1(this, products);

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
}

void fillData() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        products.add(new Product(columnTags, i * 100,i * 553
               , false));
    }
}

public void showResult(View v) {
    String result = "Selected Product are :";
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (p.box){
            result += "\n" + p.name;
            totalAmount+=p.image;
        }
    }
    String total="Total="+totalAmount;
   // Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n"+"Total Amount:="+totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("res",result);
    bundle.putString("tot",total);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2Activity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: post the related code...image doesn't help reading code...

Comment: Your code is different with your image.And your code is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of your `add()` requires a `String[]` and you are passing it a `String`.

Just change ,

`products.add(columnTags[i],i*100,i*553,false)`

to

`products.add(columnTags,i*100,i*553,false)`

Also do the following,

```
for(...)
{
    String temp = columnTags[i];
    products.add(temp,i*100,i*553,false)
}
```

**EDIT**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  fillData();
  ArrayAdapter boxAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(products.name)));

  ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
  lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
}

void fillData() {
 String temp;
 for (int i = 0; i <columnTags.length; i++) {
   temp = columnTags[i];
    products.add(new Product(temp, i * 100,i * 553, false));
  }
}
```

Comment: Error:(54, 53) error: no suitable method found for setText(String[])
method TextView.setText(CharSequence) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to CharSequence)
method TextView.setText(int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to int)

Comment: This will only eliminate your error but I strongly suspect it wont work for you since your programming logic is wrong.

Comment: Can you share your code rather than posting an image of your code so that i can edit your code.

Comment: Actually i need to display All the columntags value in my listView

Comment: Your code is not clearly visible since the tooltip of the error is coming in the way.

Comment: "Unfortunately Application has been Stopped" Im getting error like this.

Comment: Actually I have to display a String Array in my listView. Please help me to implement it.

Comment: do i have to modify anything in Product class?

Comment: Process: arun.com.listwithchecks, PID: 1606
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{arun.com.listwithchecks/arun.com.listwithchecks.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
            at arun.com.listwithchecks.MainActivity.fillData(MainActivity.java:32)
            at arun.com.listwithchecks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java

Comment: Please check my Question section I have added the log cat.

Comment: Thank You so much Dude . i got the output! Once again Thanks for your support.

Comment: Cheers :) Mark it as the selected answer if it helped you.